# how to hide content outside of my UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have some UITableView, the cells content just gets out of the cell with excess, in the following illustration A is not wanted, but B is wanted

how to achieve B and avoid A

[image]

Comment: Hello Zazu i Think You can take one view in that tableview cell and put all content in it and set that view height width as cell height width

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after a lot of search, I had to add this line in my custom cell class and got it solved ! :)

```
override func awakeFromNib()
{
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.clipsToBounds = true;
}
```

Comment: If you had to do this, maybe there's something wrong in your code

Comment: How did you do a lot of search between the time your question was asked (12min ago) and your answer (12min ago, too) ?

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo I asked and answered in the same time, stackoverflow allows this, please don't have doubts, I just want to help others, thanks.

Comment: It was just surprising, i looked at the answer, discovered you did a lot of search and realized the question was asked at the same time ^^

Comment: no problem my friend, now this is added here so people will benefit from it, now i go back to work :)